# Jsf Component Tree or ManagedBeans are used while rendering?

Tags: jsf

While render response phase , jsf mechanism  uses managed beans or components tree  for generating form values or view? I think if validation fail tree is used otherwise beans are used. is that  true?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, both are used; it is up to the component to decide whether (and when) it reads which EL-expressions.

Components with failed validation / conversion will generally use the unconverted submitted value, others will evaluate the EL-expression. Component state not bound by EL-expressions will come from the component instance, even though other state on the same component might be read anew from the EL-expression.

Comment: *What* didn't you understand?

Comment: I implemented a phase listener with PhaseId.anyphase and syso in getter setter functions it seams while renderding; if there is a value binding  with no exception, bean is used otherwise component tree is used a I wrong